# Laravel & inertia.js file download

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I uploaded a file to the database and created Storage link using "php artisan storage:link" and everything work perfectly but when I want to download the file I face this error [image]

here's my code

route

```
Route::get('/download/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\SubjectController::class, 'downloadFile'])->name('subject.download');
```

Vue.js

```
<inertia-link :href="'/download/'+slide.id" class="rounded-lg bg-gray-200 px-4 py-1">
      <Icon name="download"></Icon>
</inertia-link>
```

the Controller

```
    public function downloadFile($id) {
        $file = Upload::find($id);
        $subjectCode = $file->subject()->get()->map->only('name','code')->first()['code'];
        $subjectName = $file->subject()->get()->map->only('name','code')->first()['name'];
        return response()->download(storage_path('app/public/documents/'.Str::upper($subjectCode.'_'.$subjectName).'/'.$file->file), 'public');
    }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

replace

```js
<inertia-link :href="'/download/'+slide.id" class="rounded-lg bg-gray-200 px-4 py-1">
                                    <Icon name="download"></Icon>
                                </inertia-link>
```

to

```js
<a :href="'/download/' + slide.id" class="rounded-lg bg-gray-200 px-4 py-1">
    <Icon name="download"></Icon>
</a>
```

then it will not handle by `inertia` and it will let you download file

Comment: Thank you for you respond this method works, but I need to know why didn't work with inertia.js is this error related to inertia.js?

Comment: `inertia` link act as ajax call to get next page like pjax so download won't work here it try to get next page it is diffrent then `<a>` tag

Comment: I have been struggling with this issue and could find anything about the problem until I started to reason that Inertia could have something to do, unfortunately Inertia docs do not make any clarification on this.