# Is There Any Way to Download a File (PDF) in the Controller After Inertia.js Post?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am using Laravel 8 with Jetstream Vuejs and Inertiajs and I am trying to download a PDF that's generating in my controller.

I post my form's data:

```
previewPDF() {
      this.$inertia.post("/tracker/preview-pdf", this.form);
    },
```

Then in my controller I select the required data and generate the pdf for download:

```
function previewPDF(Request $request) {
       
       $pdfData = $this->getPDFData($request);
       $domainData = $this->getDomainData($request);
       $hourSumData = $this->getHourSumData($request);
       $userData = Auth::user();
       
       $pdf = PDF::loadView('trackerPDF', ['pdfData' => $pdfData, 'domainData' => $domainData, 'hourSumData' => $hourSumData, 'userData' => $userData]);

       return $pdf->download("pdfname.pdf");
   }
```

Due to the fact I posted the data with Inertia, my response is shown in a modal like so:

[image]

The general thought on this seems to be to just not use Inertia for file downloads: [Laravel & inertia.js file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65558569/laravel-inertia-js-file-download)

Is there any way to do this while still using Inertia? If not, is there proper way to handle this posting all of my form's data and not just an `<a>` link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inertia requests must have an Inertia response. So you would be correct in saying that you shouldn't use Inertia for this request.

Try following the answer in the [post you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65558569/laravel-inertia-js-file-download) which is using `<a></a>` instead or make an Axios request.

Something like (not recommended):

```
 axios.post('/previewPDF',
  { data: this.form },
  { responseType: 'blob' })
  .then(res => {
    let blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: res.headers['content-type'] });
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = item.slice(item.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    link.click()
  }).catch(err => {})
```

Comment: @Andrew could you update your main post with the solution you came up with?

Answer (score 0):

just use traditional form action, it will fully render a page and not just Link to inertia.

in form, instead of submit.prevent, use action=route/link with your form input name and id like in your controller. I just did this and it works fine.

Sorry if i dont explain this well, im still new to this coding world